# Rspec ruby rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I'm trying to get a create action to set up properly.

I keep getting an error: `ArgumentError: Unknown keyword: topic`

Here is the testing:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe TopicsController, type: :controller do

let(:my_topic) { Topic.create!(name: RandomData.random_sentence, description: RandomData.random_paragraph)}
describe "POST create" do
it "increases the number of topics by 1" do
  expect{ post :create, {topic: {name: RandomData.random_sentence, description: RandomData.random_paragraph}}}.to change(Topic,:count).by(1)
end

it "assigns Topic.last to @topic" do
  post :create, { topic: {name: RandomData.random_sentence, description: RandomData.random_paragraph}}
  expect(assigns(:topic)).to eq Topic.last
end

it "redirects to the new topic" do
  post :create, {topic: {name: RandomData.random_sentence, description: RandomData.random_paragraph}}
  expect(response).to redirect_to Topic.last
end
end
```

Here is the controller:

```
  def create
@topic = Topic.new
@topic.name = params[:topic][:name]
@topic.description = params[:topic][:description]
@topic.public = params[:topic][:public]

if @topic.save
  redirect_to @topic, notice: "Topic was saved successfully."
else
  flash.now[:alert] = "Error creating topic.  Please try again"
  render :new
end
end
```

I'm trying to figure out what I'm missing that is causing this error I've been staring at it for hours and have tried to edit it multiple times to no avail.  I can't figure it out.  The rest of the project I've been working on has been okay however I cannot figure out why I can't get the word topic to convert successfully.  Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `post` method takes keyword arguments as a second argument.

If you need to specify `params`, the `params` keyword should be used:

```
post :create, params: { topic: { name: ..., description: ... } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `:topic` with `:params`. That's the expected keyword for your test. It is already clear to `RSpec` that you're testing for `Topic` since your spec file is `TopicsController`.